# no default constructor exists for class

Tags: наследование, c++

Класс Mesh содержит все нужные функции для работы с моделями. Классы Box и Sphere наследуются от него, при этом имея свои конструкторы.

```
class Mesh
{
public:

    void move(float x,float y,float z)
    {
            ...        
    }

    void turn(float x,float y,float z)
    {
            ...
    }

    void flip()
    {
            ...
    }

    void setTexture(char filename[])
    {
            ...
    }

    void setSize(float x,float y,float z)
    {
            ...
    }
};

class Box : public Mesh
{
public:

    Box(float x,float y,float z)
    {
        ...
    }
};

class Sphere : public Mesh
{
public:

    Sphere(float x,float y,float z, int segments)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Дело в том, что сейчас мне нужно написать конструктор для Mesh, который будет грузить 3D модельки, но когда я пишу что то подобное в Mesh

```
Mesh(float x,float y,float z,char filename[])
{
    ...
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку " no default constructor exists for class ". Если добавить пустой конструктор
    Mesh();
то появляется ошибка

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Mesh::Mesh(void)" (??0Mesh@@QAE@XZ)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выражение **Mesh();** является *объявлением* конструктора без параметров. Конструкторы унаследованных классов **Box** и **Sphere** неявно вызывают конструктор базового класса **Mesh()**, поэтому у него должна быть *реализация*, например пустая:

```
Mesh() {}
```

или реализация по-умолчанию (доступно в C++11):

```
Mesh() = default;
```

До того, как вы добавили новый конструктор с четырьмя параметрами, компилятор создавал пустой конструктор за вас, опять же, неявно.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.

Comment: @hashcode_: Тогда отметьте ответ как верный (там есть галка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 0):

У меня этот код нормально откомпилировался. У вас ошибка линковки. Попробуйте удалить все сборочные файлы и откомпилировать заново.